# Why do installers not open in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, wamp, windows-server-2016

I've downloaded a few different wamp packages on my Windows Server 2016 machine but none of the installers will launch. Nothing happens when you double click the installers after downloading. I've updated Windows, allowed "side loaded apps" in Control Panel, I've tried running as administrator... Running out of ideas. I was able to install Firefox, but so far no other installers will launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server admin responded back as soon as I posted the question...

"A new Windows 'feature' recently added through Windows Update now requires you to unblock all applications downloaded from an external source.

Right click on the .exe you wish to use, select properties, then click unblock at the bottom."